# How to set select as default selected value in ng-option in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to set select as default selected value. Instead for me ng-option first value is setting as default selected value.

**My Controller :**

```
$scope.mdPreferencelist = [];
$scope.mdPreferencelist.push('Tv', 'Film', 'Theatre', 'Ad Film', 'Digital', 'Social Cause', 'Others');
```

**HTML :**

```
<select name="preference" class="form-control1 drop" required  ng-model="model.preference" placeholder="select" ng-options="item for item in mdPreferencelist" ng-change="addmdPreference($index)"><option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/jezHjO2ZTcGRWmqDiGMT?p=preview. Post a plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: That said, it's a bit contradictory to disable an option if you want it to be selected. And the `selected` attribute is unnecessary, too. The model drives what is selected.

Comment: Thanks I just want the same

Comment: Have u using angular.js - 1.5version?   Because I am using 1.2 version and I am not getting as your dropdown. I don't know whether it is due to version problem or something else

Comment: Same result with 1.2.32: http://plnkr.co/edit/iuRWiOYvBYbieFLHKyfu?p=preview (not sure why you're using such an old version, though). Post a plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working. I just copied ur angular.js link and I used it in my code. Now it is working like a charm